# How do I click a button using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to press a button in TeamSpeak using applescript, here is my code:

```
tell application "TeamSpeak 3 Client" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "TeamSpeak 3"
        click menu item "Connect" of menu "Connections" of menu bar 1
        delay 2
        click button "Connect"
    end tell
end tell
```

and here is an image of me hovering over the button in accessibility inspector

[image: Accessibility Inspector inspecting a push button]

All I want to be able to do is figure out how to push my button using the information given to me in Accessibility Inspector, but with my code I get the error "System Events got an error: Can’t get button "Connect" of process "TeamSpeak 3"." Here is a screenshot of the window the button is directly inside:

[image]

Comment: There is [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/) tool which allow to figure our the GUI hierarchy, so it's easier to track the buttons. See related [SE post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5612277/55075).

Answer (score 13):

You also need to specify the parent objects.

```
activate application "TeamSpeak 3 Client"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TeamSpeak 3"
    click menu item "Connect" of menu "Connections" of menu bar 1
    click button "Connect" of window 1 of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86715/discussion-on-answer-by-user495470-how-do-i-click-a-button-using-applescript).